# Spark join/groupby datasets take a lot time

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 datasets(tables) with **35kk+** rows.

I try to **join**(or **group by**) this datasets by some id. (in common it will be one-to-one)

But this operation takes a lot time: **25+ h**.

Filters only works fine: **~20 mins**.

**Env**: emr-5.3.1

**Hadoop distribution**:Amazon

**Applications**:Ganglia 3.7.2, Spark 2.1.0, Zeppelin 0.6.2

**Instance type:**  m3.xlarge

Code (**groupBy**):

```
Dataset<Row> dataset = ...
...
.groupBy("id")
.agg(functions.min("date"))
.withColumnRenamed("min(date)", "minDate")
```

Code (**join**):

```
...
.join(dataset2, dataset.col("id").equalTo(dataset2.col("id")))
```

Also I found this message in EMR logs:

```
HashAggregateExec: spark.sql.codegen.aggregate.map.twolevel.enable is set to true, but current version of codegened fast hashmap does not support this aggregate.
```

Comment: Is your data skewed ? Do you have NULL ids in either datasets?

Comment: What if  you try `dataset1.join(dataset2, "id")`?

Answer (score 1):

There Might be a possibility of Data getting Skewed. We faced this. Check your joining column. This happens mostly if your joining column has NULLS

Check Data Stored pattern with :

```
select joining_column, count(joining_col) from <tablename>
group by joining_col
```

This will give you an idea that whether the data in your joining column is Evenly distributed